# Cannot connect SignalR in React

Tags: reactjs, signalr

I am trying to setup a connection to SignalR using @microsoft/signalR package. See below code for my implementation

```
    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .withUrl(`${serverURL}`, {
     transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
      })
    .build();

connection.start({transport:'webSockets'});
```

Every time I launch the code it's giving several errors below.

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this? I've tried several other ways of connection, such as skipping negotiation, and also tried another set of documentation seen here using HTML and JS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy